# Add existing file to GitHub repo just by using GitHub.com

Tags: git, github

I'm new to GitHub and have looked everywhere to find the answer to this. I have a folder with 4 files in it i want to put on a GitHub repo i made here https://github.com/Cubit-Games/BlockDistract. Is there no way to simply "upload" files to it without having to download GitHub or use the GitHub terminal? I just want these 4 files to be in that repo. It really cant be that hard but from what iv looked up it is that hard. Please help!

Comment: GitHub is not about uploading files. It is about using git. If you didn't want to use git, why did you use GitHub?

Comment: i just thought that since i see a lot of open source software and programs on GitHub, i might as well post mine on there to have a better chance of being seen.

Comment: And git is how you "post" it. It is a _git_ hub.

Comment: ok i just manned up and quickly learned the git terminal, i was being pretty stupid before, my program is up now.

Comment: ill just delete this question since now its just wasting space on stackoverflows server :P

Comment: ok nvm, i cant delete it, oh well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple...

Just download [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), clone your GitHub repository to your local machine, add the 4 files you want, commit locally to your repository, then push it to GitHub.

You can do all these steps using the GitHub Desktop (on Windows or OSX).

Answer (score 1):

Github does allow you to create and edit files in their UI. So if the files are text based you can simply copy paste them into it.

Github doesn't have an "upload" feature in its UI because why would it? It's based on git repositories which have a distinct way to put files on other servers. It's not DropBox.